# Data mapping tools like dataweave

Tags: javascript, java, integrations

I’m planning to build a data mapper (Java object <-> XML <-> JSON, etc) as robust as DataWeave and more advanced than AtlasMap to support my integration workflow. Which basically can parse the structured data like XML, JSON, EDI, etc. and map to another schema with a different format with the ability to execute functions between them, any suggestions on how would I go about it? Either Java or JavaScript. Are there any existing libraries or opensource project which I can take look at?